# Calling then twice that contains response on axios

Tags: javascript, axios, promise, chaining

How to call then twice with same response object?

```
function a() {
  return axios.get('/foo').then(function(resp){
    // do something with resp, eg. if 401 then force local state to logout
  })
}

// the caller:
a().then(function(resp) {
  // not called, I want same resp, not just data
}).catch(console.log).then(clearLoadingBar)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your promise to return `resp`, you will need return it:

```
return axios.get('/foo').then(function(resp){
  // do something with resp, eg. if 401 then force local state to logout
  return resp;
});
```

Comment: ok seems working :3